# How can I send one characters each time instead of one word in selenium with C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wrote the following code.
Instead of sending "LHR" I want to send it in 3 sentence each character each time.

```
        IWebDriver driver;
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/travel/flights?hl=en-US");
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#i15 > div.e5F5td.BGeFcf > div > div > div.dvO2xc.k0gFV > div > div > input")).SendKeys("LBH");
```

Comment: Question is not stated enough, please provide more detail

Comment: I want to send the word "LHR" (It's an airport) in 3 sentence,
1. to send 'L'.
2. to send 'H'.
3. to send 'R'.
Since I can't send "LHR" in one word (It's sending only L and then exit the program).

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and I am able to send all three or more character together, please use the action method to do it like below.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
ele = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("yourselector"))

action.moveToElement(ele).click().build().perform();

action.moveToElement(ele).sendKeys('LAHORE').build().perform();
```

***Import***

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions
```

***Make sure to use the correct locator.Also, i tested with java, I am sure you can change it to desire language***

Comment: @Erez Levy - if this solve your issue, so please accept the answer.